# Passing Results from 2 Queries in a Single Route in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I am trying to get posts from all users, plus tasks from only the current user. All passed into a single page with a single function and route. It returns an error page instead.

**Controller**

```php
public function getDashboard()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $userId = $user->id;
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $tasks = Task::where('employee_id', $userId )->get();

    return view('dashboard', compact('posts', 'tasks'));
}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@getDashboard',
    'as' => 'dashboard',
])->middleware('auth');
```

**Blade/View**

```php
<div>
    @foreach($tasks as $task)
        <p data-taskId="{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_body }}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: Sorry that was not clear. The stuff up top is what I was trying to accomplish, but of course it didn't work. I tried the compact() as well as with()  but always with a broken page. If I remove the post one, it works foreach task, if I remove the tasks it return correctly with foreach post. Cannot get both to work. always get undefined tasks

Comment: It's @foreach($posts as $post)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like possibly a syntax issue, as compact should work fine.  Try this in your controller:

```
return view('dashboard', compact('posts', 'tasks'));
```

Then in your view, make sure to use the variables and not the class name, and as Karl Hill said, it's used within `()`, not `{{}}`:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   {{$post->nameOrWhatever}}
@endforeach

@foreach($tasks as $task)
    {{$task->nameOrWhatever}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I updated my code there to reflect what it is now. I am still getting an error saying that tasks does not exist.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Your code is correct.  If the error is coming from the controller (from compact, not the loop), it may an issue with $userId, or the Task class has an issue.  The for loop should never have this problem, as the $tasks variable will at the very least store an empty collection.  Try dumping $tasks before the return statement in getDashboard().  I suspect there is something failing when trying to get the collection, rather than any of the code you've written for your question (it all looks good). Not relevant, but on your data in HTML, change to data-task-id

Comment: ok. you think this could be an error with the Task Model then? I can follow that for a minute because as you stated, I can find nothing wrong with the other code at all. I got the same code to work in a different place with a different route. /taskList instead of /dashboard.

Comment: Sorry - I can't say.  That's sort of a different question, and you'll have to backtrack  / trace dumps through other areas to see.  I do think what you have up there now is correct for what you asked though.

Comment: I don't know why and I wish I did, but I moved everything into my taskController under a new function Name and route change of which view to return. it works. Somehow it was the /dashboard that was causing the error. because if I route to /dashboard it fails, but if I call it /anythingElse, it works.

Comment: LOL.  Glad you got it solved.  If the answer was helpful, please mark as correct.

Comment: If you can answer why it worked with the same code in a different controller I will gladly mark that as correct. I sued my same code. But just moved it over which no one had suggested I do. I really would love to know the why in this so I can duplicate ir.